# Simple C udp client/server fails

Tags: c, sockets, unix, udp

I am trying to write a server program that just displays any raw data it receives from anyone through udp. A client can send some data to it at any time. No errors appear except for "Socket error: Resource temporarily unavailable" which in other words mean that `recvfrom` has no data to receive (because it's presumably not getting any packets).

The client just sends "test!" to 127.0.0.0:12345, while the server listens with a non-blocking socket on port 12345. It may be worth noting that I am on linux.

Why is `server` not displaying the packets that it's obviously being sent from `client`? I don't see what I'm missing.

## common.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_in;
typedef struct sockaddr sockaddr;

int createSocket(uint16_t port)
{
    int handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if (handle <= 0)
    {
        printf("failed to create socket\n");
        return 0;
    }

    sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(handle, (const sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0)
    {
        printf("failed to bind socket\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int nonBlocking = 1;
    if (fcntl(handle, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK, nonBlocking) == -1)
    {
        printf("failed to set non-blocking\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return handle;
}

int sendData(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c, uint32_t d, uint16_t port, int handle, char* packet_data, int packet_size)
{
    uint32_t address = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d;

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(address);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    int sent_bytes = sendto(handle, (const char*)packet_data, packet_size, 0, (sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    if (sent_bytes != packet_size)
    {
        printf("failed to send packet (%d/%d)\n", sent_bytes, packet_size);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

## server.c

```
#include "common.h"
#include <time.h>

void main(void){
    int socket = createSocket(12345);
    if (!socket){
        perror("Socket error");
    }
    int true=1;
    setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void*)&true, 1);
    // so that we can immediately reuse the port if the server stops running

    char buffer[100] = "No data";
    if(!listen(socket, 0)){
        perror("Socket error");
    }

    //struct timespec delay = {0,33333333}; // 30Hz
    struct timespec delay = {0,100000000}; // 100Hz

    int running = 1;
    int ret = 0;
    while(running){
        ret = recvfrom(socket, &buffer, 100, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (ret < 0){
            perror("Socket error");
        } else if (ret > 0){
            printf("%d: %s\n", ret, buffer);
        }

        nanosleep(&delay,NULL); 
    }
}
```

## client.c

```
#include "common.h"

void main(void){
    int socket = createSocket(0);
    printf("Started client on port %d\n", socket);

    if(!sendData(127,0,0,0,12345, socket, "test!", 5)){
        perror("Socket error");
    } else {
        printf("Sent data.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `listen` for UDP. [man listen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html): "The sockfd argument is a file descriptor that refers to a socket of
type SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_SEQPACKET". That is, listen is only for TCP.

Comment: `if(!listen(socket, 0))`. That check is wrong. `0` means success. So you should check for `-1` and you'll see you get an error there.

Comment: perhaps use 127.0.0.1: https://www.howtogeek.com/149227/whats-the-difference-between-127.0.0.0-and-127.0.0.1/

Comment: also consider using [`inet_aton`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton) to convert the string "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" ipv4 address to the binary address

Comment: @yano sending to 127.0.0.1 gives me the following error from `client`: "Address family not supported by protocol" (addr.sin_family = AF_INET as defined in common.h)

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the "classic" loopback address, there should be no problems whatsoever sending to that. I don't know enough to know if 127.0.0.0 will work, but the article I linked suggests not to use it. The error you're getting sending to 127.0.0.1 isn't because of the address, it must be elsewhere. It's also possible you have a firewall mucking with things. Do have netcat installed? That's great to use when debugging client/server problems, since it inserts a known, working entity in one of those positions, eliminating variables and unknowns on one side of the conversation.

Comment: @yano turns out you were right! There was another issue that messed the whole thing up. See answer.

Comment: @kaylum thanks, removed that.

Comment: ....and you send an array of 5 chars that is not NUL-terminated to the peer where you assume the datagram is NUL-terminated:(

Comment: Header files should 'never' contain source code (unless the function is being 'inlined', which yours is not.  Suggest adding a third file that contains the source code from `common.h`

Comment: @MartinJames good catch. I now set buffer[ret] to 0.

Comment: @user3629249 what's the reasoning behind this? Why do I need one dummy file (.h) and one meat file (.c)?

Comment: a `.h` file is NOT a dummy file.   A `.h` file is for things that need to be visible in unrelated files.   Since that `.h` file is very likely to be included in multiple `.c` files any data instance or source code in the `.h` file will be duplicated each time that `.h` file is included

Answer (score 0):

I passed a pointer to `address` where I was supposed to pass a pointer to `addr` in common.h -> sendTo().

On top of that, I was sending packets to 127.0.0.0 when that should have been 127.0.0.1 (thanks @yano).

Corrected code:

```
int sendData(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c, uint32_t d, uint16_t port, int handle, char* packet_data, int packet_size)
{
    uint32_t address = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d;

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(address);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    int sent_bytes = sendto(handle, (const char*)packet_data, packet_size, 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    if (sent_bytes != packet_size)
    {
        printf("failed to send packet (%d/%d)\n", sent_bytes, packet_size);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: note to self: rename "addr" to "remote" or "server"